# Connection lost when receiving emails with Exim4

Tags: exim, sa-exim

A few days ago I have had errors to receive emails in Exim4 from a specific host.

Errors like this appear in my log:

```
SMTP connection lost after final dot H=example.com [IP-ADDRESS] P=esmtp
SMTP connection from example.com [IP-ADDRES] lost while reading message data (header)
```

Is this a problem with my server or with the server that sends the emails?

Other services like Gmail or Outlook do not display this error and are normally received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SMTP connection lost after final dot H=example.com [IP-ADDRESS] P=esmtp

This means the server didn't send the `QUIT` SMTP command. It's not a huge problem (the mail has already been delivered by that time), although chances are pretty high that the mail which was just delivered was actually spam, and not a genuine email (genuine email senders don't usually drop the connection like that).

> SMTP connection from example.com [IP-ADDRES] lost while reading message data (header)

This means the connection dropped *during* the transmission of the email itself. Barring any bugs in the sending server, this will be considered a temporary failure, and the sending server will try again after a suitable delay.

In general, you shouldn't need to act upon these messages. If they occur a lot for some sender that you know to be a genuine sender, you might want to verify if there is any connectivity problem between you and the sender.

The more likely case though is that someone's trying to sell you small blue medical pills.

Comment: How can I check for problems between my server and the sending server?

Because these errors are occurring several times in recent days only for the same sending server.

Comment: Is possible add this is server in SpamAssassin whitelist to not delivered as spam?

Comment: I don't know, how do you check for connectivity problems? Call your ISP? ;-)

Comment: I was able to contact the technical department of the sending host and they explained that the problem was in their servers.